# no suitable driver found for oracle10g while integrating spring3.0 to jsf 2.0?

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, jdbc

i am trying to integrating  spring to  jsf without using maven.i put springbeans.xml in  web-inf and i have created managed beans  in  facesconfig.xml. i am trying to draw connection from the springbeans.xml. i have inserted my project hirarchy image. ojdbc7.jar is being put in classpath for connecting oracle10g and jdk1.7.

my `facesconfig.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation=
"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee        
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-  facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
 version="2.0">
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>loginController</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>myCode.LoginController</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>UI/login.xhtml</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/UI/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>registered</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/UI/Home.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>unregistered</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/UI/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>UI/login.xhtml</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/UI/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>register</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/UI/Registration.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>

</navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>UI/Registration.xhtml</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/UI/Registration.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>Registration</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/UI/Registration.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

my `springbeans.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"></property>
<property name="username" value="system"></property>
<property name="password" value="admin"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

`logincontroller.java`

```
 package myCode;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;


@ManagedBean(name = "login", eager = true)
public class LoginController implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String userName;
    private String passWord;
    //private boolean chkbox;
    DriverManagerDataSource dms;
    private BeanFactory factory;


    public ResultSet rst;
    public Statement stmt;
    public Connection conn;
    String qry = "select username from regdusers where username='" 
            + getUserName() + "' AND password = '" + getPassWord() + "'";

    /*public LoginController() throws SQLException{

        loginAction();

         //rst=stmt.executeQuery(qry);

    }*/
    public String getUserName() {

        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }

    public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }

    /*public boolean isChkbox() {
        return chkbox;
    }
    public void setChkbox(boolean chkbox) {
        this.chkbox = chkbox;
    }
    */
    public int insertNewUser() throws Exception {

        String qry = "insert into regdusers  values('" + getUserName() + "','" + getPassWord() + "')";

        String st = loginAction();
        System.out.println(st);
        if (st == "unregistered") {
            return stmt.executeUpdate(qry);
        }

        return 0;
        //return jdbcTemplate.update(qry);

    }


    public String loginAction() throws SQLException {
        org.springframework.core.io.Resource rs = new ClassPathResource("SpringBeans.xml");
        factory = new XmlBeanFactory(rs);
        dms = (DriverManagerDataSource) factory.getBean("ds");

        System.out.println("springs stared ....");
        conn = dms.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String qry = "select username from regdusers where  
        username = '"+getUserName()+"' and password = '"+getPassWord()+"' ";

        if (conn != null) {

            rst = stmt.executeQuery(qry);
            if (rst.next()) {

                return "registered";
            }
            return "unregistered";
        }
        System.out.println("null came");
        return "unregistered";
    }


    public String RegisterHere() {
        return "register";
    }


}
```

`mylogin.xhtml`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
    <title> Please Login</title>
</head>
<f:view>

    <body>
    <h:form>enter image description here
        <h1>
            <h:outputLabel>Applicant Login</h:outputLabel>
        </h1>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="user name"></h:outputText>
            <h:inputText value="#{login.userName}"></h:inputText>
            <h:outputText value="password"></h:outputText>
            <h:inputSecret value="#{login.passWord}"></h:inputSecret>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{login.chkbox}" id="remember"/>
            <h:outputLabel>Remember me</h:outputLabel>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandButton id="login" value="Login" action="#{login.loginAction}">
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:panelGrid>
            <h:outputLabel>Need an account?</h:outputLabel>
            <h:commandLink action="#{login.RegisterHere}">
                Sign Up
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
    </body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

when try to login with my html form ,it is showing no suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe in jsf project

Comment: After all, it does seem your Oracle jar is either not the correct one, or not on classpath.

Comment: where is ojdbc.jar and which version ojdbc jar you are using?

Comment: am using oracle7.jar . does it not compatible for my project?could oyu suggest me which to use?

Comment: its already being put  on classpath

Comment: do  i need to show my web.xml?

Comment: i dint add any listner for spring in the web.xml.

Comment: yep it is working.....thank u  for  ur quick response